# Synthesized property and variable with underscore prefix: what does this mean?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Underscore prefix on property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582448/underscore-prefix-on-property-name)

What does this mean? `@synthesize window=_window;` I know that in general it means that 'some class' has a window, but why use `_window` instead of just `window`? Is this a namespace thing?

Comment: check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521254/prefixing-property-names-with-an-underscore-in-objective-c

Comment: Duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521254) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371489) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582448/) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837559/) [and so on...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=objc+property+underscore)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'll give a go at describing this programming convention in basic English.

It is a very common convention in other languages to name member variables with a preceding `m`, `m_`, or `_` to distinguish them from locally declared variables and to signify that they should have accessors written, if necessary (no `classInstance.m_Variable = 5`).

If an Objective-C programmer declares ivars following this convention (and they should) and uses the basic syntax `@synthesize _window;` then the usage for the property becomes somewhat ugly: `classInstance._window = myWindow` or `[classInstance set_window:myWindow]`.  Using the syntax `@synthesize window=_window;` allows the Obj-C programmer to utilize a popular programming standard (preceding ivars with `_`) while simultaneously having property accessors that use the Apple standard `classInstance.window = myWindow` and `[classInstance setWindow:myWindow]`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common thing to do in iOS programming/objective-C, it has to do with ivars. For more information you can read here:

[Why rename synthesized properties in iOS with leading underscores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466496/why-rename-synthesized-properties-in-ios-with-leading-underscores)

[How does an underscore in front of a variable in a cocoa objective-c class work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work)

Based on my experience in having this habit in my code, it helps me to accidentally writing window when you mean self.window and vice-versa (doesn't have to be window, but any other variables as well)

Answer (score 3):

short answer is: the underscore is just a convention useful to stress the fact that class variables are "private" to a class and you should access them via their properties.

you could declare your `window` variable without the leading underscore; in this case the @synthetize statement would be simply: `@synthetize window`, and it would be practically the same.

for the long answer, the links posted by aherlambang are really interesting read...