# Objective-C: `@synthesize fooBar;` vs. `@synthesize fooBar=_fooBar;`

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synthesized property and variable with underscore prefix: what does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049269/synthesized-property-and-variable-with-underscore-prefix-what-does-this-mean)

I've seen both of these in code; what's the difference?

```
@synthesize fooBar;

@synthesize fooBar=_fooBar;
```

Comment: Which is itself probably a dupe: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521254) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371489) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582448/) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837559/) and [so on...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=objc+property+underscore) Please search before posting; the system helps you do this by showing links to related questions while you're typing yours in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@synthesize fooBar;` creates accessors for the property `fooBar` using an instance variable with the same name for storage, while the `=_fooBar` tells the compiler to use the instance variable named `_fooBar` as storage instead. You don't need to use the `=...` if you have your instance variables and properties identically named, and you do otherwise.