# concept of instance properties

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

would you please break my confusion.

If I define a property in a class

```
@interface Class
{
  UIScrollView * _scrollView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView * scrollView;
@end

@implement
@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
@end
```

When I wanna implement it, I can use

```
_scrollView.contentSize = xxx
```

or

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = xxx
```

What's the difference between the two description?

---

Thanks for your answering...

Comment: Hot Licks' answer is correct.  You might also be interested in this answer to help clarify things. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8032148/470879

Answer (score 2):

The direct reference to the instance variable is precisely that -- a reference to a field in the instance, unaffected by the fact that it's also the "backing store" of a property.

The `self.propName` reference, on the other hand, is shorthand for either `[self propName]` (if reading) or `[self setPropName:newPropValue]` (if setting).  Ie, those references go through accessor methods.  This isn't real important if the property is defined as `assign`, but if it's `retain` then the setter method takes care of all the retain logic.

Further, you can implement your own property accessors -- `-(SomeType*) propName {...}` and `-(void) setPropName:(SomeType*)propParm {...}` -- if you want to have them do something special, such as "lazy" initialization.

(Also, properties default to "public" access, while instance variables default to "private" access.)