# Obj-C @synthesize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prefixing property names with an underscore in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521254/prefixing-property-names-with-an-underscore-in-objective-c)

iPhone App Developer Beginner here:

in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize detailDescriptionLabel = _detailDescriptionLabel;
```

I'm used to seeing

```
@synthesize detailDescriptionLabel;
```

the `= _` is throwing me off, what is this doing?

Comment: Also: [How does an underscore in front of a variable in a Cocoa Objective-C class work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work) and [Underscore prefix on property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582448/underscore-prefix-on-property-name)

Comment: iOS 5 is under NDA;  edited to not violate that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each property is backed by an instance variable. The language allows for them to be named differently. By doing `@synthesize detailDescriptionLabel = _detailDescriptionLabel;`, you're basically saying that use `_detailDescriptionLabel` as the backing instance variable for the property `detailDescriptionLabel`. If you just do `@synthesize detailDescriptionLabel;`, it implicitly understands that the instance variable has the same name.

Comment: Note that user code should not employ the preceding underscore character: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002931-BBCFHEAB

Comment: That's true. But then, have you looked at the code generated by XCode 4's interface builder. It does add the underscore most of the times.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Odd that new Xcode used to keep the name the same, but it's default code changes the name of the instance variable

Comment: @e.James: Thanks for the link, but I read "using an underscore character as a prefix for an instance variable name is allowed".

Comment: @Graham Lea: yes, Apple has revised that document since last year. The preceeding undersocre on instance variables is now considered normal.

Answer (score 0):

n .h

```
    UILabel *_detailDescriptionLabel;
}
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize detailDescriptionLabel = _detailDescriptionLabel;
```

This line means that the property "detailDescriptionLabel" will have a setter and getter for the class attribute named "_detailDescriptionLabel"

If the name was the same, you will have

```
@synthesize detailDescriptionLabel;
```