# Whats the use of having synthesize statement

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Obj-C @synthesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317631/obj-c-synthesize)
>   [Synthesized property and variable with underscore prefix: what does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049269/synthesized-property-and-variable-with-underscore-prefix-what-does-this-mean)

Whats the use of having synthesize statement like this

@synthesize popOverTableData = _popOverTableData;

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It simply states that the backing variable for popOverTableData is _popOverTableData. Normally without this, and just doing @synthesize popOverTableData means that the backing variable is called the same.