# Xcode4 templates now use underscore on iVars?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode3to4

I have noticed that with Xcode4 Apple has updated the application templates to include underscores before instance variables.

```
// Xcode4
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@synthesize window = _window;
```

.

```
// Xcode3
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@synthesize window;
```

I know there are differing opinions on the [usefulness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521254/prefixing-property-names-with-an-underscore-in-objective-c) of this but I was just curious if the updated templates where:

- (1) Highlighting a new best practice.
- (2) Showing how Apple does things but meaning for you to do it the old way.
- (3) Its just personal taste, it does not matter.

Comment: Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work) question.

Comment: In this case it's correct, because it's referring to an ivar declared in an Apple framework.  You still shouldn't use single leading underscores for your own ivar names.

Comment: Thank you @ NSResponder, thats what I was looking for, much appreciated ...

Comment: I don't think NSResponder is right. Because Apple's own documentation now recommends it in your own variables. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/03_AddingViewController.html. Rather, it looks like a reversal of policy by Apple, and a good one I think because there's less confusion between ivars and the properties that access them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's interesting because in the past (pre-iOS), Apple used to [discourage the use of underscore prefixes for ivars](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281):

> Avoid the use of the underscore character as a prefix meaning private, especially in methods. Apple reserves the use of this convention. Use by third parties could result in name-space collisions; they might unwittingly override an existing private method with one of their own, with disastrous consequences. See “Private Methods” for suggestions on conventions to follow for private API.

But with a modern Objective-C runtime, I believe ivar naming conflicts in subclasses has been eliminated, so this is not a problem anymore.  So I think that's why they're making the templates use an underscore prefix by default, to match what Apple's internal code looks like.

Comment: Ivar naming conflicts haven’t been eliminated — if a superclass declares an ivar in its `@interface` block, no subclass may declare an ivar with the same name. That said, the modern runtime features the non-fragile ABI, which allows _class extensions_ to define their own ivars, which in certain cases allows the removal of ivars from the `@interface` block entirely which, in turn, helps with preventing name conflicts.