# ViewController = _ViewController meaning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prefixing property names with an underscore in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521254/prefixing-property-names-with-an-underscore-in-objective-c)

I just started iphone App development and noticed that when you generate a new project, the following code can be seen in AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
```

AND in the AppDelegate.h file it says

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController controller;
```

I would just like to know what exactly this means, particularly the synthesizing part. Is it
instantiating a local private variable? If so, how is this different from saying
@synthesize viewController;

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7174277/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/822487/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371489/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/6139593/ http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+underscore+property&submit=search

Answer (score 6):

The pattern `@synthesize foo = bar;` allows you to define a property of key `foo` which gets synthesized in combination with an instance variable of name `bar` (or `_foo` if you want), while `@synthesize foo;` simply synthesizes a property and instance variable with the same name (`foo` that is).

```
@property (...) Foo *foo;
@synthesize foo = _foo;
```

is kind of equivalent to this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    //result of @synthesize...:
    Foo *_foo;
}

//result of @property...:
- (void)setFoo:(Foo *)foo;
//result of @property...:
- (Foo *)foo;

@end

@implementation MyClass

//result of @synthesize...:
- (void)setFoo:(Foo *)foo {
    _foo = foo; //simplified!
}

//result of @synthesize...:
- (Foo *)foo {
    return _foo; //simplified!
}

@end
```

The synthezised instance variable would the be used via either `_foo` or `self->_foo` (of which the former actually is an implicit form), which would involve no accessor method call whatsoever.

While the synthezised property would the be used via `self.foo`, which would then utilize a call to one of the synthesized accessor methods.

Just think of `@synthesize foo;` as an implicit `@synthesize foo = foo;` (note the lack of an `_` here, equal names).

Answer (score 5):

More or less. These lines in the .h declare the existence of two public variables called window and controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController controller;
```

But these lines only declare the existence of the variables, they don't actually create them. It's up to the class to implement these however it wants - they could be virtual variables for example, that don't actually exist but call methods that create data programmatically, or load it from a database or something.

These lines in the .m file actually create ("synthesize") the variables.

```
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
```

What these lines actually say is that the internal variable name is _window, but the public name of the variable is window. That means that within the class you can access the variable directly by saying

```
_window = something;
```

But externally you have to access it using

```
appDelegate.window = something;
```

Because that's it's public name. You can also access it internally to the class using self.window.

Another interesting fact of Objective-C is that using dot syntax to access variables in this way is really just a handy way of calling setter and getter methods to access them. SO the synthesize line, in addition to creating a variable called _window, is also defining the following two methods:

```
- (void)setWindow:(UIWindow *)window; // to set the _window variable
- (UIWindow *)window; // to get the _window variable
```

And you can call these methods directly if you like, using

```
[self setWindow:someValue];
UIWindow *window = [self window];
```