# Property vs instance variable in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prefixing property names with an underscore in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521254/prefixing-property-names-with-an-underscore-in-objective-c)

I'm trying to understand the ivar vs property naming conventions.  Something to the effect of

```
@interface someClass : NSObject {

NSArray *_array;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *Array;
```

then in .m file

```
@synthesize Array = _array;
```

What is the benefit of doing it this way, if any?  I guess maybe I'm not sure if I understand the property vs ivar relationship exactly right.  Maybe it has to do with calling self.Array and distinguishing the two?  Any enlightenment would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: This question came up yesterday. And last week.

Comment: Note that iVars and methods should always start with lowercase letters.