# cellForRowAtIndexPath: not called

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

My app has two states: logged in and not logged in, and I have the following architecture (vastly simplified):
- ViewController A which contains a search box and a table view.
- ViewController B which is used for logging in the app.

The flow is the following:
- the user is not logged in;
- A is pushed on the stack. In `viewWillAppear` I check if the user is logged in and if yes, an async network request is being made and, once that is done, the table is loaded with the data from the network. However since the user is not logged in at this point, the table view is empty;
- the user taps on the search box; because he's not logged in, B is pushed (after a confirmation);
- he logs in successfully in B, then presses a button which pops B and shows A again;
- at this point in time, because he's logged in, from `viewWillAppear` I do the async request;
- when that is completed, I call `reloadData` on the table view.

What I notice is that `numberOfRowsInSection:` is called and it returns the correct result, however `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is NOT called afterwards and the table remains empty.

I've checked and `reloadData` is called on the main thread.

Any idea what can it be? Cause it's driving me nuts!

Thanks,
S.

EDIT: Here's the async bit of code from `viewWillAppear` in A.

```
if ([User isLoggedIn]) {
    [self.asyncRequest fetchDataWithCompletionHandler:^(id response, NSError *error) {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        if (error) {
            [Utils displayError:error];
        } else {
            self.array = response;

            self.isLoaded = YES;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f) animated:NO];
        }
    }];
}
```

I've checked that the async request completes successfully and that `response` contains the correct data (this is the array used to back the `UITableView`).

After `reloadData`, I've put a breakpoint in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and it stops there and it returns the correct number of elements in `array`. After that, however, the breakpoint in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is never hit.

Comment: The correct method selector is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` not `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: If numberOfRowsInSection: is returning correct data, I think there might be problem with setting the delegate and datasource. Can you post some code??

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's that one. I've pasted here the short version.

Comment: The delegate and the data source are set in Interface Builder, to the File's Owner (i.e. A).

Comment: Also, another point: this works well afterwards, i.e. if, after I log in, I switch away from A, then I come back to it, the table gets populated correctly. Only when I return to it from B doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it is. If I push A from another VC then it works correctly. So the problem only appears when I have: A (empty cause the user is not logged in) -> B (user logs in) -> A again, as B was popped.

Answer (score 297):

One valid scenario for why `numberOfRowsInSection` would be called but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would not be called is when the size or positioning of the table does not require any rows to be displayed.

For example, let's say you had a table that was 20 pixels high, but the header for the first section was 30 high and you returned nil for the header (or did not implement `viewForHeaderInSection`). In this case, no rows would be displayed and it would look like the table just isn't there.

I see you are using IB. The sizing of the table can be deceptive in IB as it is assuming header and footer sizes. I would log the frame for the table so you understand where it is when the appliction is run (versus where it appears in IB). I would also be sure to manually size and position the table's frame *before* calling reloadData. This will solve this valid case where `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called.

Comment: This guy knows what he's talking about.

Comment: What a great an answer here, @joel just gave a very good explaination. I actually ran into a similar issue and I took almost one day for debugging. In my case, the cellForRowAtIndexPath func won't be called. With this answer, I found out the AutoLayout has calculated height for table to be 0. And that's the root cause, App determined not to render the cell at all.

Comment: I'm so sick of letting Xcode suggest the constraints for views. My table view never showed up because of some $#!tty constraints it suggested. Changed the constraints and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: I had a slight variation on this. I placed a UITavleView with IB without using auto-layout. The frame of the table view was set to automatically stretch to the height of the cell. In the .m file I set the height of the frame of the cell, and the height of the frame of the table view. XCode ignored my code set frame the first time it displayed the table view, but respected the setFrame call the second time. When I disabled auto-stretch in the Y axis my problem went away and the setFrame methods worked as expected. XCode constraints are painful some days. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: how can the header be 30 but then you returned `nil` for it? Are you talking about if one has implemented `heightForHeaderInSection` and he's returning 30 but then for the `viewForHeaderInSection` has returned `nil`?

Comment: @Honey yes, that's the example given. However there are numerous reasons why the table might not have any rows to display based on the positioning and sizing.

Comment: Let's say: you had a table that was 20 pixels high, but the header for the first section was 30 high and you **returned a view** for the header

Comment: Totally on spot. My tableView had height 0. Saved me a good headache!

Comment: Hint to log your tableView's frame: `NSLog(@"tableView size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.tableView.frame.size));`
For me it turned out that I had wrong constraints set. The size told me it's correct.

Comment: For me, it was in a vertical UIStackView and had width 0. Putting equal widths with the stack-view solved it. I wish I found this answer sooner!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have set the tableview height 0 for some reason. Then my cellforrow never called. I was worry about this. but This answer helped me out.

Answer (score 45):

Check that the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is not returning 0.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem as the original author.  This method is returning 1, as shown in your answer, and is being called... yet cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called.  The datasource and delegate are set to the file's owner through Interface Builder; I've even tried setting it by code (tableView.delegate = self) and still it's not called.  Just thought I'd contribute these factors since the author hasn't accepted an answer but you seem to be on the right track.  Hope someone can figure this out!

Comment: According to Apple "The default value is 1." This method isn't needed.

Comment: It absolutely was needed at the time of answering this question.

Comment: I can confirm that this method returned 0 and was causing trouble. I've implemented it to return 1 in my table view controller and everything was fixed.

Comment: Its returning 3 for me.

Answer (score 29):

I had the exact same issue and the problem was that I was trying to call reloadData: from another thread. The solution would be:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: I had numberOfRowsAtIndexPath being called but not cellForRowAtIndexPath. after adding this, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using a different dataSource, as I was, make sure you are retaining the dataSource. Merely instantiating the class that will be the dataSource and assigning it via `tableView.dataSource = myDataClass` will not be sufficient as the dataSource property of a tableView is weak and will be released when viewDidLoad completes. All of the other methods were being called for me — even, surprisingly, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` — so this took me some time to debug.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. For `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, it's in the delegate that's why it has been called anyway.

Comment: this is so valid

Answer (score 13):

If a Table View inside a view that conflicts something like Scrool View, it does not called. You should separate the views in your Storyboard or *.xib file.

```
// True
    ▼ View
        ► Table View
        ► Scrool View
        ► Constraints

// False
    ▼ View
        ► Scrool View
            ► Table View
        ► Constraints
```

Answer (score 12):

```
// For others showing up on this questions via Google, etc.
// Check and make sure you've set the table view's data source and delegate.
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 9):

We had the same/similar issue. The code reached `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` (and it even returned values) but could not reach `cellForRowAt`. At the time, Table View in the Storyboard had only constraints for right side, left side and top, but not for bottom. Once we added constraint to the bottom, it worked like a charm.

So, check that you provide all needed constraints for the Table View.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Pretty damned near the last thing anyone would suspect too, even though it kind of makes some kind of sense in retrospect.

Comment: Months later, nailed by the same issue... Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using auto layout like me and adding tableview to your view controller's view make sure you have added this line when you are allocating your table view.

```swift
tableView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Silly mistake from my side.

Comment: Saved me hours haha. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Everyone keeps talking about height, but my `TableView` in a `StackView` with leading alignment ended up with 0 width.

Make sure to check if your `TableView` is correct size using `Debug View Hierarchy`.

Comment: and what was your solution? Mine is inside a stackView, but still I don't see it the debugger

Comment: @Honey you might want to set its height constraint to a constant and disable scrolling.

Comment: Actually I just removed it out from the stackview, still didn't make a difference. Other methdods get hit, but not `cellforrowatindexpath`. FYI it's a tableView inside a UIView...

Comment: @Honey not sure how to help with this amount of information, make sure to not return 0 in numberOfRows :)

Comment: same issue i have use table view inside stack view not cellForRowAt indexPath not working

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem  because my Subview on which i added the `UITableView` was not allocated so it was returning nill and tableview was not calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but `numberOfRowsInSection` getting called

Answer (score 3):

Wasted hours and then found out that my tableview was inside a stackview. As soon as I removed the stackview, it worked like a charm. For me it's Xcode 11.3 .

Answer (score 2):

I am using a customer datasource and it was released. Because it is a weak reference of tableview.

Answer (score 2):

This is embarrassing and perplexing, but here's my fix.

My code:

```
_scanResultTable.delegate = self;
_scanResultTable.dataSource = self; // self's lifecycle was fine, wasn't getting released
[_scanResultTable reloadData];
```

So the weird part is: the identifier _scanResultTable was never declared in my code, anywhere in the project.  I have no idea how this compiled (and I recompiled several times).

My root cause was that I had linked my table output to `scanResultTable` in my ViewController, but was referring to it as _scanResultTable.  Once I started using `scanResultTable` like I should've been, things cleared up.  This makes me wonder if objective-c has something special about leading underscores in identifiers...

Edit: [It does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521254/prefixing-property-names-with-an-underscore-in-objective-c)!  Good lord I can't wait to never touch this language again.

Comment: Solved the issue for me too. <3

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had the `TableView` inside a `StackView`. When I put it outside the StackView it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ReactiveCocoa. So I've created the model for table view. The data was prepared to be displayed, so `numberOfRows` and so on was called. But I haven't added the tableview as subview, thus `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was not called)))

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Make sure self.data isn't nil!
    // If it is, you'll always return 0 and therefore
    // cellForRowAtIndexPath will never get called.
    return [self.data count]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe too obvious but in my case i was deleting an element (Label) which was a reference to the top margin of my table programmatically, so it was not a problem with delegate/source but of the table having some problems with the content-size / height, this conflict created a weird behaviour, calling numberOfRowsInSection but not cellForRowAt indexPath

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that after the user logged in and B is popped the `viewWillAppear` method in A gets called in order to perform the refresh?

If you show B as a modal controller, when you dismiss it you won't have the `viewWillAppear` method called.

As far as I know, `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear` (and other like it) are events generated by the UINavigationController in the case of navigation events (push/pop viewcontrollers). 
So maybe that is why you eventually get your refresh when you leave A and return ... it all depends on the way to display the next viewcontroller.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I've put breakpoints in the code and I see they're hit. It all works fine up to the point where tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should be called.

Comment: Then i'm out of ideas. Maybe if you post some more code we can spot a possible mistake. But something is definitely fishy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert new rows manually instead of `[self.tableView reloadData]`:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
    for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.count; i++) {
        _rowsNumber += 1;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    }
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

In dataSource method return incremented `int _rowsNumber`:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _rowsNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved same issue by checking tableViewCell identifier. Go To Attributes İnspector and look at identifier section. Probably is missing. So write cell identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Same case here, but it was a mistake:

I included a Scrollview with 2 tablesViews inside a ViewController (design requirements), in the scrollview controller I created the ViewControllers (that contains the TableViews) programatically and I used a **weak var** to store it, **bad idea** because they were released at the end of viewDidLoad method.

**If you don't see your tableview content, please, check if it was released.**

My mistake was very brain-painful for me because all methods (delegate&datasource) were called except viewForCell...

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue 
i have use Table View inside the StackView and table view scroll disable and set height constrain but after that

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Not working stop calling this method all `Data Source` and `Delegate` set properly.

if you have same issue than Solution is set Table View  bottom , leading , trailing constrain

[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here helped me.

I was using doing my constraints programmatically but forgot to write:

```
myTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your constraints are correct and none of them is removed at build time.