# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called but numberOfRowsInSection called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a simple problem but I can't understand what is. 
I have a `UIViewControler` (called `RootController`) that load a `UIView` (called `SecondView`) that contain a `tableView`. The problem is that the `UIView` call the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and the `numberOfRowsInSection` but don't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the table view is not displayed. 
The code of the `RootViewController` is:

```
SecondView *secondView = [[seconddView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:secondView];
```

And the code of the `SecondView` is:

```
@interface SecondView () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView *table;
@end

@implementation SecondView
@synthesize table;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
   self.table = [[UITableView alloc] init];
   self.table.delegate = self;
   self.table.dataSource = self;
   [self addSubview:self.table];
   }
 return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }
  cell.textLabel.text = @"Prova";
  return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return 1;
}
```

Can you help me to find the problem? Thank you.

Comment: What is the table view frame?

Comment: The previous answer solves it but the real explanation is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712325/cellforrowatindexpath-not-called][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712325/cellforrowatindexpath-not-called

Comment: Right answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712325/cellforrowatindexpath-not-called

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to set the Frame of `UITableView`

Comment: You should expand on your answer -- one-line answers aren't really helpful.

Comment: I'm using UITableViewController. Having the same problem. What is the solution for mine?

Comment: Did set the frame

Comment: Or setup tableView's constraints

Answer (score 14):

My problem was that I had a simple class doing the implementing of my delegate and data source, but the lifetime of the simple class was too short.

I was doing

```
MyDataSourceClass* myClass = [[MyDataSourceClass alloc] initWithNSArray:someArray];
tableView.dataSource = self.tableViewDataSource;
tableView.delegate = self.tableViewDataSource;
[tableView reloadData];

// end of function, myClass goes out of scope, and apparently tableView has a weak reference to it
```

Needed to be doing

```
self.tableDataSource = [[MyDataSourceClass alloc] initWithNSArray:someArray];
tableView.dataSource = self.tableDataSource;
tableView.delegate = self.tableDataSource;
[tableView reloadData];
// now at the end of the function, tableDataSource is still alive, and the tableView will be able to query it.
```

Note that the code above is pseudocode from memory.  Take from it the concept of "make sure your data source/delegate lives long", but don't copy paste it, because there's other stuff you need to do (like set your frame etc etc).

Comment: Thank you for the "lifetime of the simple class was too short", this was my issue

Comment: Thank you! This was my problem, just needing to set it as a variable in the viewControllers memory and reference that when setting the datasource  did the trick.

Answer (score 11):

This could also happen if reloadData is called on a different thread. Make sure it is run on the main thread since all UI stuff has to happen on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

In XCode6 same weird problem was occurring to me when "Add Missing Constraints" is applied on tableView on Storyboard to adjust views.

To resolve this issue on Storyboard first clear constraints:

[image]

then apply constraints in following fashion:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can only call the viewcontroller's view **AFTER** viewDidLoad is called.
You can't interact with self.view in your init method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.table.delegate = self;
    self.table.dataSource = self;
    [self addSubview:self.table];
}
```

In your case, you need to init your tableview with a frame (like a suggested in the code above). Just make sure you add the code in viewDidLoad in your viewController

```
SecondView *secondView = [[seconddView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60,     self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:secondView];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue like you:

I have only one method from delegate protocol that called and this is **numberOfRowsInSection**. Meanwhile I have second method **cellForRowAtIndexPath** that was not called.

The reason of this behaviour was that my **numberOfRowsInSection** returned 0 rows and **cellForRowAtIndexPath** didn't call because it needed to draw 0 cells.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment on Hussain Shabbir's answer, to clarify it, but as I am not yet able to comment, I will post an answer instead.

I had exactly the same issue. `numberOfRowsInSection` would fire, but `cellForRowAt` would not. I tore my code apart looking for the reason, but the reason is not in the code.

The solution (for me) was in the storyboard. I had not set constraints for the Table View. **Select the table view, click the "Add New Constraints" icon** (looks like a square TIE fighter) and set constraints for top, bottm, leading and trailing. Then `cellForRowAt` will be called and your table will populate.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This solution was specific for my case but maybe helps someone.

I had the same problem. I was using a computed property instead of stored property; so every time I call the tableView, I was getting a new one.

I had this code:

```
var tableView: UITableView{
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.register(SomeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    return tableView
}
```

And this is the fixed code:

```
lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.register(SomeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    return tableView
}()
```

Answer (score -3):

Delete UITableView and add again in your ViewController