# Why isn't cellForRowAtIndexPath fired but other methods are?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

`numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` are both called on my table. The array I'm using has 3 items in it.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called. What would cause this behavior?

Comment: Have you connected the tableView to the delegate and data source? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Yes - otherwise the two functions would not fire. What code do you want to see?

Comment: Do your two other methods return values that aren't equal to zero? If they return 0 then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't called.

Comment: 1 and 3 are the values returned.

Comment: Any other code in your VC that might interfere with the tableView?

Comment: Just the creation of an array to feed the tableview.

Comment: I'm using UIStackViews. It seems the table may not be visible. I've added a background color and it still doesn't appear.

Comment: see my answer. Seems like your tableView's dimensions are too small, so `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be something to do with the dimensions of your tableView. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9354898/4431068) for details. Basically, what is says is that if your tableView is too small, then the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is never called. Try making your tableView smaller, or decreasing the size of your header or footer of the tableView. If this doesn't work, try reloading the table using `tableView.reloadData()` on the main thread.

Comment: Yes. After taking the tableview out of the StackView, cellForRowAtIndexPath is called and I see data loading in the UI.