# tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath not getting called

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata, swift2

I have a tableview which loads peripherals received from BLE. This`NSMutableArray` is maintained in the appDelegate. Whenever a new peripheral is received in the app I add it to the array.

My problem is that everything works fine on first run and the table updates accordingly and I use the app for a while. Then I reset(CoreData, UserDefaults in app) my app and go back to the initial screen.

I use the following code to get back to initial screen of my app

```
class func showStartScreen() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nav = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate)!.window!!.rootViewController = nav
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate)!.window!!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

When I reset app data and come back to the screen where I display the peripherals in the tableview, it doesn't updat. I can see that the peripherals are added in the array but when I reload the tableview `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called.
I tried to add a single dummy cell into the table and at that point `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called properly but only for the dummy cell.

`numberOfRowsInSection` returns the correct value and my datasource and delegate are correctly set too.
I clear the list every time a scan is started for BLE peripherals

In AppDelegate:

```
func discoveredPeripheral(peripheral: CAPeripheral) {
    print("added peripheral")
    var isDuplicate:Bool = false
    for object in scannedPeripherals!  {
        if object is CAPeripheral {
            let newPeripheral = object as! CAPeripheral
            // Need to add check of nil
            if newPeripheral.peripheral_UUID == peripheral.peripheral_UUID {
                isDuplicate = true
            }
        }
    }
    if (!isDuplicate) {
        self.scannedPeripherals?.addObject(peripheral)
    }
}
```

In ScanVC:

```
   func discoveredPeripheral(peripheral: CAPeripheral) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.peripheralTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Hope I have explained well. Why is `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath` not called when I clearly have data to display?

Comment: Make sure did you set delegate and datasource of your tableView?

Comment: Are you reloading the table?  Please  post the appropriate snippets of code.

Comment: @mikep have added code for adding peripherals and reloading data

Comment: @iPatel yes I have checked for datasource and delegate. They are set correctly.

Comment: Make sure you also see [cellForRowAtIndexPath: not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712325/cellforrowatindexpath-not-called)

Answer (score 0):

If you say that you come back to initial viewController after cleaning CoreData and UserDefaults, I assume that it is why you don't see anything in your tableView, because you store found peripherals into CoreData and you clean it? Call `discoveredPeripheral` when you come to initial controller.

Comment: I don't store peripherals in core data. I make a new search every time my ScanVC is loaded. I have mentioned that I receive the data but cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called when reloading the table view.