# How to Get the Height of a RTLabel

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

Does anyone know how to get the height of a RTLabel?

What I need to do is to adjust the height of the parent view of the RTLabel base on the same RTLabel height.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get height of RTLabel use "optimumSize" property

```
RTLabel *someLabel = [[RTLabel alloc] init];
someLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 300.f,100.f);
someLabel.text = @"<p>Some <b>HTML</b></p>";
CGSize optimumSize = [someLabel optimumSize];
someLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 300.f,optimumSize.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just

```
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(rtLabel.bounds)
```

Comment: A bit nicer would be to read it out using `CGRectGetHeight()`, i.e `CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(rtLabel.bounds);` Also, Apple has suggested not to name ivars with [leading underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521254/prefixing-property-names-with-an-underscore-in-objective-c), just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Updated, I was just using the project for RTLabel from Github -https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel, but change it to just rtLabel.