# Why _window is accessible without defining UIWindow *_window?

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is a follow-up question of: [Why rename synthesized properties in iOS with leading underscores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466496/why-rename-synthesized-properties-in-ios-with-leading-underscores)

in `MyDelegate.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyAppDelegate

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyMainViewController *mainViewController;

@end
```

in `MyDelegate.m`

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize mainViewController = _mainViewController;
```

Besides what's explained in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466496/why-rename-synthesized-properties-in-ios-with-leading-underscores) about the benefit of the `_` prefix, I am wondering why `_window` is accessible

```
@synthesize window = _window;
```

without defined anywhere, before it is used for the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is both the declaration and definition. The `@synthesize` directive is capable of creating both accessor methods and instance variables. From TOCPL, ["Declared Properties: Property Implementation Directives"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9):

> You can use the form `property=ivar` to indicate that a particular instance variable should be used for the property...
>   For the modern runtimes (see [“Runtime Versions and Platforms”](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH106) in Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide), instance variables are **synthesized as needed.** If an instance variable of the same name already exists, it is used.

So if you already had a declaration of an ivar,

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject
{
    NSWindow * _window;
}
```

that would be used (and this was required in the "legacy" platform). Otherwise, it is created by the `@synthesize` directive. The result within the class is the same in either case, although it should be noted that synthesized variables are created as if they were declared with the `@private` directive; subclasses can access the property, but not the ivar directly. More investigation at the inimitable Cocoa With Love: [Dynamic ivars: solving a fragile base class problem](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
 @synthesize window = _window;
```

It's defined there. This is saying, you know that property I said was called `window`, well, in the background, make this an ivar called `_window`, so that if anyone types

```
window = blah blah
```

This gives a compiler error.

This prevents you accessing the ivar directly by accident instead of using the synthesized accessors.