# Leading underscores in generated code

Tags: ios, iphone, compiler-construction

When reading apple generated template code as well as in documentation, I see `_` (underscore) and `__` (double underscore). Example would be the code generated on checking off core data option:

```
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

What does each of this mean? I understand `_` refers to a backing private variable. What does `__` mean?

Comment: Guess it has been explained very well in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466496/why-rename-synthesized-properties-in-ios-with-leading-underscores

Comment: It's just a naming convention ... don't know what's __ is trying to say though, maybe it's an even more private variable.

Comment: Bruce Li, I saw that link, it does not mention anything about double underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's documentation suggest NOT to use single underscores in your project (as it reserved by apple itself: best-known example is _cmd ). But underscore is traditional  c-style modifier for privateness of identifier, so double underscore is a solution to make private identifier for your variable.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html

> Names of most private methods in the Cocoa frameworks have an
>   underscore prefix (for example, _fooData ) to mark them as private.
>   From this fact follow two recommendations.
>
> ```
> Don’t use the underscore character as a prefix for your private methods. Apple reserves this convention.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Its often confusing at first glance as to when you are using the getter/setter methods and when you are accessing the ivar directly.

The alternative is name the ivar differently from the property. A common approach is to use an underscore to prefix the ivars names, like so -

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController 
{
    NSDate *_timestamp;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *timestamp;
```

To connect the property (whose name has not changed) the sythensize statement gets an extra option:

```
@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize timestamp = _timestamp;
```

Essentially, if an ObjectiveC programmer declares ivars following this convention (and they should) and uses the basic syntax `@synthesize _window;` then the usage for the property becomes somewhat ugly: `classInstance._window = myWindow` or `[classInstance set_window:myWindow]`.  Using the syntax `@synthesize window=_window;` allows the Obj-C programmer to utilize a popular programming standard (preceding ivars with `_`) while simultaneously having property accessors that use the Apple standard `classInstance.window = myWindow` and `[classInstance setWindow:myWindow]`.