# Why do auto-generated IBOutlet @properties not use the @synthesize button = _button convention?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, properties, nib

If I control-drag a UI element (for instance, a UITableView) from my NIB to my .h file it will generate code like this:

```
// .h
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

// .m
@synthesize tableView;
```

However, many people seem to think that this would be preferable in the .m file

```
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
```

The reasons are that it forces you to access the ivar via the property setters and getters (or use the dot-syntax self.foo) rather than directly. And it avoids naming conflicts in method names... for instance the **tableView** in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Why then does the auto-generated code not follow this convention?

Comment: Because the guy who created the template doesn't like that convention? All of Apple's boiler plate and sample code is a mashup of different coding styles and conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pace of evolution of Objective C and the Cocoa framework has increased since the introduction of iOS. The answer to this question and insights into properties in Objective C 2.0 are discussed here: [Why rename synthesized properties in iOS with leading underscores?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5466496/564322)