# What of the mean of underline in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does an underscore in front of a variable in a cocoa objective-c class work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work)
>   [Why rename synthesized properties in iOS with leading underscores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466496/why-rename-synthesized-properties-in-ios-with-leading-underscores)

I am a green hand in iOS programming.

I always see such a statement in other's code

*@synthesize textNoteOrLink = _textNoteOrLink;*

What is the meaning of the underline anyway? Can we just 'textNoteOrLink' in that case.

Comment: its an underscore and is used to differentiate the instance variable from the property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466496/why-rename-synthesized-properties-in-ios-with-leading-underscores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can just write `textNoteOrLink`.

Many developers put an underscore at the start of instance variable names (@synthesizing a property actually adds an ivar for that property) to avoid accidentally using the ivars instead of the property, bypassing setters and getters.

IMHO it's a good thing to do, but if you don't like it, just don't use it, but be cautions not to confuse properties and ivars.

Comment: Yes. It is just like prefixing a variable with m or g in C++ to indicate member or global respectively.  The underscore separates the property from the iVar that contains its value.

Comment: just for beginners: IVAR stands for instance variable :-)