# Objective c synthesized property ivar

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does an underscore in front of a variable in a cocoa objective-c class work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work)
>   [Prefixing property names with an underscore in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521254/prefixing-property-names-with-an-underscore-in-objective-c)

When we declare a property and then synthesize it like this for example:
@synthesize name = _name;
So, the _name is an instance variable for the name property we are gonna use in the following implementation.
My question is why we need this ivar and what would happen if i didn't create the _name ivar?
Thank you.

Comment: And here's the other 16: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5582448/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6049269/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371489/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7174277/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5659156
http://stackoverflow.com/q/837559/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6146244/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/10651535/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6124109/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8145373/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3521254/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6064283/ 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/9696359/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5521499/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5466496/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114587/

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that there is a default ivar name, which is the same as the property name. One of the reasons for specifying your own, with an underscore, is to eliminate ambiguity in your setter:

```
-(void) setFoo:(id) foo {
  // here, foo should ONLY refer to the passed-in var
  // If your ivar is the same, it is ambiguous.
  // If your ivar is _foo, then there is clarity.
}
```

Comment: oh,i see. So like in java, it will be like this: this.name = name,in order to make it clear that the right hand-sided name is the argument, but in here we just use _name to distinguish this,right?

Comment: Yeah, in some languages you must use `this` or `self` or something to access instance variables, but not in Objective-C. It may appear as though self.name is the same as just saying name, but the two are really very different. self.name *sends a message* (it is virtually identical to [self name]). just using name is directly using a variable.