# What does = operator in @synthesize mean?

Tags: objective-c, synthesize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does an underscore in front of a variable in a cocoa objective-c class work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work)
>   [Underscore prefix on property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582448/underscore-prefix-on-property-name)

I'm new to XCode.
I see where someone has:
@synthesize msgTextField = _msgTextField;

and later they refer to the _msgTextField.

Q: Is the @synthesize statement creating a variable called _msgTextField?

Q: Why would it be backwards from an assignment operator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Underscore prefix on property name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5582448/) http://stackoverflow.com/q/6049269/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371489/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7174277/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5659156
http://stackoverflow.com/q/837559/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6146244/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/10651535/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6124109/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8145373/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3521254/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6064283/ 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/9696359/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5521499/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114587/

Comment: Thanks Josh!  I'm following these links and am learning a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes the @synthesize will generate an instance variable in that case of _msgTextField;
2. Its not an assignment, its telling @synthesize specifically the name of the ivar to generate.

Comment: Remember that @synthesize is no longer needed.  Properties will autogenerate the ivar with an underscore in front of it.

Comment: When was this added? Xcode 4.5/iOS 6, or earlier?

Comment: Xcode 4.5 I believe - its not a feature of iOS its a compiler feature.

Comment: The default `@synthesize` feature was added in [Xcode 4.4](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html)

Comment: Is there any difference between 4.4 and 4.5 though? Other than one is for Lion one for Mountain Lion.

Comment: If your compiler doesnt support it you wont be able to compile.  I believe it was introduced in 4.4.