# Objective-C @synthesize syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax, synthesize

being relative new to programming iOS apps, I find it very useful to start off with some sample code.
Hence, I ended up with a .m file, that starts with some lines that look like

```
@synthesize valueOne= _valueOne;
```

I noticed that having such a syntax makes it impossible to programmatically set properties of valueOne, for instance doing things like

```
valueOne.tag = 3
```

Therefore, for my own purposes, I have outcommented the "=_valueOne" part, without any noticeable harm to the functionality of the code.

What is the significance of such syntax, and what has been the consideration of the author of my sample code to use it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And here's another 16: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5582448/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6049269/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371489/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7174277/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5659156
http://stackoverflow.com/q/837559/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6146244/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/10651535/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6124109/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8145373/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3521254/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6064283/ 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/9696359/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5521499/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5466496/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114587/

Comment: I really first tried to search for the answer. The problem is, that it is kind of difficult to phrase this in a Google-able way...

Comment: No, it's not: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=objective-c+underscore+synthesize In fact, several of those questions would have come up in the suggestions before you posted this.

Comment: @Sjakelien As you type in your question, SO shows you a list of possibly related questions. Many of the ones that appear with your question, answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, I now see them listed here to the right. I will pay more attention to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is synthesizing the backing ivar for `valueOne` under the name `_valueOne`. You can simply write your code to look like

```
_valueOne.tag = 3;
```

That said, it's generally considered better to use the property accessors whenever possible, so you'd typically write this as

```
self.valueOne.tag = 3;
```

The notable exceptions to this are when you're in `-init`, `-dealloc`, or your own custom getter/setter you still want to use the ivar directly.

---

Using a prefixed underscore on ivar names is generally considered good practice, because it means if you write `valueOne.tag = 3;` and you meant to use the property, you get a compiler error instead of silently using the ivar. If you intend to use the ivar, you can just use the underscore prefix, as `_valueOne.tag = 3;`.

This is such a common practice that the auto-synthesis behavior of modern clang will use the leading-underscore style for ivars. This means that if you delete the `@synthesize` line entirely, it will behave as though you had `@synthesize valueOne = _valueOne;`.

Comment: Do we really need yet another answer to this?