# Underscore before property name, in setter

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, synthesize

I wrote a setter method -

```
- (void)setMyProp:(MyProp *)myProp{
    _myProp = myProp;
}
```

How is underscore put before property name is working?
I know this question has been asked, but they are about user setting property name to _myProp, some convention. I am not synthesizing or changing the property name. How this underscore is working?

Comment: And here's another 16: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5582448/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6049269/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371489/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7174277/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5659156
http://stackoverflow.com/q/837559/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6146244/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/10651535/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6124109/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8145373/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3521254/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6064283/ 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/9696359/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5521499/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5466496/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114587/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest version of LLVM, then the compiler creates @synthesize for you with the syntax:

```
@synthesize myProp=_myProp;
```

Therefore you are able to use _myprop even though you have not synthesized explicitly.

<strike>**SideNote: `_myProp` makes you access the property directly, while `self.myProp` will call accessor. Always use `self.myProp`*</strike>

Comment: Your side note is incorrect. Using `_myProp` accesses the ivar directly. The property is not used at all this way.

Comment: "Always" is also wrong... You would never use it in the setter itself and should not use it in your init methods referring to the docs ;)

Comment: @rmaddy: I cut my sidenote.

Comment: @HAS: I cut my sidenote.