# What is the purpose of using an underscore in Objective-C iOS 6.1?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to iOS development. I am creating a simple app that calculates the payout of a horse bet based on the user's bet placed and the odds they enter for the horse. In XCode (4.6.3), I have the following method which is used to calculate increase the user's bet by 1 when the button is clicked:

```
-(IBAction) addBet:(id) sender {
    self.bet = [_betTextField.text intValue];
    if(self.bet > 0) {
        self.bet += 1;
        self.betTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.bet];

    }
}
```

I have declared the betTextField variable as follows in my header file: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *betTextField;`
XCode gives me an error if I do not use the underscore before the `betTextField.text` variable. Why is this?

Comment: Because the naming convention for automatic property synthesis is designed and implemented like so.

Comment: And here's another 16: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5582448/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6049269/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371489/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7174277/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5659156
http://stackoverflow.com/q/837559/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6146244/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/10651535/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6124109/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8145373/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3521254/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6064283/ 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/9696359/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5521499/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5466496/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114587/

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the underscore is to make it so that you can't accidentally use the ivar directly when you meant to use the property instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because without the underscore the name doesn't really exist. This is because of what `@property` means and what the compiler does for you behind the scenes. Basically, your property can be accessed by using `self.betTextField` (which uses the automatically defined accessor methods) or `_betTextField` (which directly accesses the instance variable).