# Calling Location in Multiple Parts of App

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

I want to use the following code to find a user's location in multiple parts of my app. To avoid complexity, I only want to have one place where I get the user's location. I would assume that I need to put it in my appDelegate and then call it somehow from the other views when I need to use it. Does anyone know what I would need to use to get the location as an NSString on the views/tabs other than my appDelegate? Thank you!

```
- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
NSString *theLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", 
locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, 
locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
return theLocation;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all of your location listener and related stuff to the app delegate, and then make `NSString *location` [property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5986516/593709) of `AppDelegate`, now whenever you get an updated location set that to `NSString *location`, in your other `ViewControllers`, when you need, access the app delegate's location property.

If you really need an updated location you can use [NSNotificationCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2191594/593709) and broadcast a notification about new location update, so the `ViewController` which really need an updated location will register itself for Notification about new location and will do stuff accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can put your code in app delegate..like this

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@public
    float latitude;
    float longituted;
}


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    if (locationManager==nil) {
        locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

        locationManager.delegate=self;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    if ([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable]) {//check service is available or not

        [self startregionMonitoring];
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - GET Location
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation");
    NSDate *eventData=newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent=[eventData timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (abs((howRecent)<15.0)) {
        NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f \n",newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

        CLLocationDistance dist=[newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation]/1000;
        NSLog(@"===================distance %5.1f traveled",dist);
        latitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        NSLog(@"lat :%+.5f",latitude);
        longituted=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        NSLog(@"long %+.6f",longituted);
    }

}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

now where you want latitude and longitude you can access [DELEGATE latitude];,[DELEGATE longitude]; where DELEGATE Is #define DELEGATE (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```