# iOS set ViewController and AppDelegate as listeners to CoreLocation model class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location, nsnotificationcenter

How do you set up the `AppDelegate` and a `ViewController` to be listeners to a model corelocation class? What are the proper design choices??

I'm interested in having a model class to implement `CoreLocation` and location updates. I'm guessing this class should be a `sharedSingleton`, because both my `AppDelegate` and `ViewController` wish to access it.

When my `viewController` calls it, I want the `CLLocationManager` to use `startUpdatingLocation`.

When the app goes into background, I want to monitor location updates in the AppDelegate using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.

My question is, how do I set up the model class to handle these different types of location updates, as well as notify the ViewController or AppDelegate that a new location is found? Using `NSNotification`? Delegation doesn't seem to work because it's a one-to-one relationship.

Appreciate your help on figuring out how to design this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13896966/593709)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have locationManager in the AppDelagete. And let the app delegate handle for you the location updates for all the application.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate...> {
    ...
    CLLocationManager* locationManager;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D myLocation;
    ...
}
@property(nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D myLocation;
...
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    ...
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    myLocation = newLocation.coordinate;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateControlersThatNeedThisInfo" object:nil userInfo:nil];   
}

...
```

In your controller:

**ViewController.m**

```
...
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourFunction) name:@"updateControlersThatNeedThisInfo" object:nil];
}

-(void)yourFunction{
   AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   CLLocation myLocation = app.myLocation;
   if(app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
          //background code
   else
          //foreground code
   ...
}
```

Comment: This all makes sense, but how do I distinguish between when my app is in the background, and when my app is in the foreground? When i'm in the background, I want to use significantLocationChange and not notify my view controllers

Comment: Hi Rohan, I have updated my answer to handle background and foreground. Please see updates in both of the classes.