# Why put underscore "_" before variable names in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does an underscore in front of a variable in a cocoa objective-c class work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work)

In objective C I am seeing lots of code with a underscore before variable names e.g _someVariable

why is that? also how to you write accessors i.e get and set method for such a variable.

Comment: upvoting because i feel we should familiar with all kinds of standard naming conventions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The underscores are often used to show that the variables are *instance variables*. It is not really necessary, as *ivars* can have the same name as their properties and their accessors.

Example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSString *_myIVar;                  // can be omitted, see rest of text
}
// accessors, first one is getter, second one is setter
- (NSString *) myIVar;                  // can be omitted, see rest of text
- (void) setMyIVar: (NSString *) value; // can be omitted, see rest of text

// other methods

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myIVar;

@end
```

Now, instead of declaring and coding the accessors `myIVar` and `setMyIVar:` yourself, you can let the compiler do that. In newer versions, you don't even have to declare `myIVar` in the interface. You just declare the property and let the compiler synthesize the rest for you. In the `.m` file, you do:

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myIVar; // generates methods myIVar and setMyIVar: for you, 
                    // with proper code.
                    // also generates the instance variable myIVar

// etc...

@end
```

Be sure to finalize the string:

```
- (void) dealloc {
    [myIVar release]; 
    [super dealloc];
}
```

FWIW, if you want to do more than the default implementation of the getter or setter do, you can still code one or both of them yourself, but then you'll have to take care of memory management too. In that case, the compiler will not generate that particular accessor anymore (but if only one is done manually, the other will still be generated).

You access the properties as

```
myString = self.myIVar;
```

or, from another class:

```
theString = otherClass.myIVar;
```

and

```
otherClass.myIVar = @"Hello, world!";
```

In MyClass, if you omit `self.`, you get the bare *ivar*. This should generally only be used in the initializers and in dealloc.

Comment: Thank you nice exaplaination and accepting because you examples are exactly what I was seeing.

Answer (score 8):

Don't do it.

Single leading underscores are an Apple internal coding convention.  They do it so that their ivar names won't collide with yours.  If you want to use a prefix on your ivar names, use *anything but* a single underscore.

Comment: I think some people also use it to avoid accidentally using raw ivars instead of accessors?

Comment: Does `__variable` (two underscores) mean extra dangerous internal then? I was aware of the convention of internal methods but I've never seen these methods until I got deep into an Apple library

Comment: two underscore is fine.

Answer (score 1):

this is a naming convention normally used for c++ to define instance variable which are private

like in a class u may have

```
private:
int __x;

public:
int GetX()
{
  return this.__x;
}
```

this is a naming convention, i was forced to use in c++. However my teacher never told us the name of the naming convention. But i feel this is helpfull and readable specially when u are not using java naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you nice exaplaination +1

Comment: Java and Objective-C are two different languages. Don't assume that just because you can do it Java, you should do it in Objective-C.

Comment: @SevenBits I guess you have not read my answer properly. I have mentioned that they normally make your variable readable. Secondly java developers normally follow camelCase notation to achieve readability. Please read answer properly before down voting it.