# why using underscore after asterisk in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pointers

why using underscore after asterisk in objective-c

```
@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{

     LeftViewController *_leftViewController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet LeftViewController *leftViewController;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does an underscore in front of a variable in a cocoa objective-c class work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to give another name to that variable. So that in the implementation file you can use

```
self.leftViewController blablabla
```

or

```
_leftViewController blablabla
```

but, TBH, I never declare these variables twice. If it's a property - let it be a property and don't declare it in @interface part. But that's just my opinion

Comment: I think your answer implies that `self.leftViewController` and `_leftViewController` are functionally equivalent, but they're not. The former will use the accessor/getter methods, the latter will directly access the variable. This is important for a number of reasons, particularly memory management.

Answer (score 3):

In some style guide it was pointed out that it is a good habit putting an underscore in front of instance variables. That way it makes the intent clearer if dealing with the instance variable directly (`_foo`) or the property (`foo`).

( Sometimes people forget to write `self.` in front )

Comment: and then at the time of synthesize why do they write.. _leftViewController=leftViewController;

Answer (score 2):

It's a part of the variable name. Normally used to avoid collisions.

Comment: but @property statement it mentioned as *leftViewController

Comment: It may be exactly to avoid this collision.