# What are the retain semantics of synthesized ivar?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties, automatic-ref-counting, llvm

When you create a property and the compiler auto-synthesizes an underlying ivar, does the ivar have the same retain semantics has the property, or do the retain semantics only apply to the "setter"?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *strongObject
@property (nonatomic, weak)   NSObject *weakObject

_strongObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];    // is this strong?
_weakObject =   [[NSObject alloc] init];    // is this weak?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607404/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-custom-setter-for-a-weak-property-in-objecti) question. It seems that the underlying variable has the same semantics as the property, assuming you're using ARC. You could override a setter to a strong property like this:

```
- (void)setMyObject:(MyObject *)anObject
{
   _myObject = anObject;
}
```

This means that you don't have to release before (like in non-ARC) because ARC handles this at the ivar level (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038302/objective-c-custom-setter-with-arc)).

However this is not true if not using ARC, for example assign and retain, are NOT valid for ivars, only for the properties.

Comment: Does this also mean that a direct ivar assignment with copy semantics will in fact do a copy?  Take this example: `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;` Custom setter looks like `if (_myString == nil) _myString = @"A"; return _myString;`

Comment: Hmm it looks weird (specially the return statement for a setter), but no, you need to copy it explicitly. ARC handles the retain count, not the copy operation.

Comment: My bad. Return statement shouldn't have been there.