# Clarification on Asterisks and Underscores in Cocoa Syntax

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa

I recently picked up the BigNerdRanch book on Cocoa for Mac OSX and am looking for a good explanation around the use of asterisks `*` and underscores `_` that seem to be inconsistently used throughout the language. Some examples:

These appear to be functionally equivalent:

```
NSString* myString;
NSString *myString;
```

Sometimes new variables get an underscore, while others dont:

```
NSString _myString;
NSString myString;
```

And sometimes it gets all crazy:

```
NSString *myString;
NSString *_myString;
```

I've also seen variations with asterisks in methods:

```
- (void)speechSynthesizer:(NSSpeechSynthesizer *)sender
            willSpeakWord:(NSRange)characterRange
                 ofString:(NSString *)string;
```

So what is the functional use of the asterisk or the underscore, when should you use (or not use) either, and when should they be used in combination?

Comment: * means a pointer (read up on C programming) and '_' is just another alphanumeric character that doesn't really mean anything (except as a guideline for variable names that some programmers like to use). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work

Comment: Just for clarification: The second set of variable definitions are wrong, and will not compile or crash. Objects (i.e. subclasses of NSObject must be defined with a pointer (the * thingy)). Variables which are not objects (e.g. int, float, char) must be defined without *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` indicate a pointer, which all Objective-C objects are. (You pass around pointers to these objects in memory). At a basic level these are normal C pointers. If I remember correctly You could access some data in an Objective-C object by going `object->data`, just like you do with pointers to C structs.

The `_` is a Cocoa (and some other languages) convention, meaning "a piece of data that should be considered private to this object".

Objective-C has a `@private` declaration, but it's also a relatively new addition to the language - if your code is more than 2 or 3 years old (or targeting much older versions of OS X) it might not use `@private`

Because of this initial lacking of language infrastructure, the `_` is (often) used by the Cocoa community to mark "Hey, you probably shouldn't set or read this directly, please".

So:

- When dealing with Objective-C classes you always need the `*` to follow the class name (like `NSString`), because they are always pointers. I'm confused about your `NSString somestring` line in your code - either that'll generate a complier warning or will crash when you try to use it
- The `_` indicates private data. You would do something like `NSString* _name` in a `@interface` section of your Objective-C class. You would use `_name` by itself if you were calling or operating on that data in a method in your class.

So say you created a Student class:

```
// Student.h
@interface Student : NSObject {
  NSString* _name;

}

- (NSString*) name_as_caps;
@end


// Student.m

@implementation Student
- (NSString*) name_as_caps {
   return [_name uppercase];
}
```

Here we declare a class with a "private" data member: `_name`. Our `Student` class needs to return this capitalized for some reason, so we created a method to do that, where we use `_name` and call the `uppercase` method on it.

We needed to refer to the type (or class name) or _name a few times here: once, to declare the variable. For `name_as_caps` we needed to say: `this method returns a pointer to an NSString object`, thus we used `NSString *`.

Comment: `@private` has always existed in Objective-C (at least under Apple). The new one is `@package`. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF127 Also, it's worth noting that the `_` doesn't mean anything to the compiler; it's just part of the name, used conventionally by programmers to mean (to each other) “this is private”.

Comment: Ahh good point about @private - I was thinking about methods, not data. Regardless, Apple uses _ for their private variables, so the gist is still correct :)

Comment: Actually, in the classic runtime you're explicitly not supposed to use the _ prefix for your variables, because they may collide with Apple-defined variables in superclasses. (That's why most books use a _ suffix instead.) However, in the modern runtime, that collision isn't a problem, and Apple now recommends using the _ prefix when you're defining a slot variable to back up a property (especially with synthesize.)

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to Ryan's answer, when you see something like

```
-(void)speechSynthesizer:(NSSpeechSynthesizer *)sender willSpeakWord:(NSRange)character
RangeofString:(NSString *)string;
```

the things like `(NSSpeechSynthesizer *)sender` just state the type of the argument - in this case NSSpeechSynthesizer*