# iOS: Usage of self and underscore(_) with variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, self

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does an underscore in front of a variable in a cocoa objective-c class work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work)

I have been very confused with using self or underscore with variable name after synthesizing it like below:

```
In .h file:
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *users;

In .m file:
@synthesize users = _users;
```

Based on my understandings when I use `self.users`, OS will make sure to release previously allocated memory in set method so we don't need to take care explicitly.

`_users` is an instance variable for users and should be normally used while accessing the users variable. If I use `_users` to change its value then it won't fire KVO delegate which will not notify a class observing users value change.

Moreover, `self.users` allows differentiating dummy variable in the method name like below,

```
- (void)assignUsers:(NSMutableArray*)users {
      self.users = users;
}
```

Could someone please tell me if there is anything that I understood wrong or missing while using `_users` or `self.users`?

Comment: Hi @qegal I went through that thread and if you read my question, most of points are the conclusion points but what I couldn't get is when to use what!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it helps to consider how properties are (or might be) implemented by the compiler.

When you write `self.users = array;` the compiler translates this to `[self setUsers:array];`
When you write `array = self.users;` the compiler translates this to `array = [self users];`

`@synthesize` adds an ivar to your object (*unless you added it yourself*), and implements the `-users` and `-setUsers:` accessor methods for you (*unless you provide your own*)

If you're using **ARC**, `-setUsers:` will look something like:

```
- (void)setUsers:(NSArray *)users
{
    _users = users; // ARC takes care of retaining and release the _users ivar
}
```

If you're using **MRC** (i.e. **ARC** is not enabled), `-setUsers:` will look something like*:

```
- (void)setUsers:(NSArray *)users
{
    [users retain];
    [_users release];
    _users = users;
}
```

* - *Note that this is a simplified, nonatomic implementation of `-setUsers:`*

Comment: The only answer on this topic that talks about the difference from a reference counting perspective with such elegance. Excellent.

Answer (score 31):

when you are using the `self.users`, you access the property via the setter or getter.

when you are using the `_users`, you access the property directly skip the setter or getter.

---

here is a good demonstration of it:

```
- (void)setUsers:(id)users {
    self.users = users; // WRONG : it causes infinite loop (and crash), because inside the setter you are trying to reach the property via setter
}
```

and

```
- (void)setUsers:(id)users {
    _users = users; // GOOD : set your property correctly
}
```

this is the point in the case of the getter as well.

---

about the basic memory management (in case of `MRR` or `ARC`): **the iOS will dealloc the object if there is no more strong pointer which keeps it alive**, no matter how you release the pointer of the objects.

Comment: dear **Down-voters**! I would have been honoured to get some feedback about why your hands were shaking above the down-voter button, because – you believed or not – I'm not a mind reader to figure out it. thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure at all how you meant that: _"You show an abuse of `self` and ..."_, could you elaborate please? the _good demonstration_ is showing the __difference__ between bypassing and calling the _same_ setter inside the setter, which'd cause infinite recursive loop and it crashes when the stack is overflowed – therefore the final approach is avoiding causing infinite loops in runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's pretty much correct.  A couple of minor points:

iOS doesn't automatically release an object just because you use dot notation.  It releases an object when the property is declared as `copy` or `retain` (or `strong` in ARC).  If, for example, you are using non-ARC code and the property is declared as `assign`, it won't release the object.

With the latest version of the developer toolchain (Xcode 4.4+), you no longer have to manually synthesise properties - they are automatically synthesised (with the leading underscore).

Comment: Thanks Jim. I tried Xcode 4.4 with iOS 6 and yes it doesn't require synthesising properties but would that App work on lower version of iOS?

Comment: Yes - from the official documentation: [The default `@synthesize` feature requires no special SDK or runtime support.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011649-SW11)  Questions like that, you should read the documentation.