# Objective C _underscore vs self.variable

Tags: objective-c

I know this question has been asked before but possibly not in the same context. My question is that I have a singleton class that is only dipatched_once in the lifetime of the app. In the class I have some methods that are accessing the instance variables and acting upon if they have been set on the instance. This is example of how I am attempting to access them:

// .m file:

Interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) BOOL userLoggedIn;
```

Implementation:
// method:

```
-(void)someMethod{
    if(!_userLoggedIn){
    } 
    else {
    }
}
```

I know I can also use self to evaluate the value like this:

```
-(void)someMethod{
    if(self.userLoggedIn){
    } 
    else {
    }
}
```

Wondering which is correct way of accessing the value? I am not synthesizing the properties since they are all declared in the interface only in the .m file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It depends, but if you have `-(BOOL)userLoggedIn{}` implemented, that could change the behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: Usage of self and underscore(\_) with variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175229/ios-usage-of-self-and-underscore-with-variable)

Comment: If `userLoggedIn` is only defined for use in the implementation and you are using direct access to the variable, is there a reason you are declaring a property at all? Why not just use an instance variable (as in `@implementation { BOOL userLoggedIn; } ...`?

Answer (score 6):

It depends.

Do you want the accessor invoked or not?   `_variable` is direct access. `self.variable` invokes `-variable`, which is automatically synthesized by the compiler.

The former does not trigger KVO when the value changes.  The latter does.  That may be a feature or anti-feature.

But, whichever you choose, **especially for write operations**, make it consistent or else you'll be tracking down bugs in the future.

---

A general rule:

- access directly in -init/-dealloc
- access through setter/getter (dot syntax) everywhere else

---

Note also that direct access will not respect `atomic`.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by invoked or not invoked variables?

Comment: @randomorb2110 `_variable = 10;` directly sets the instance variable. `self.variable = 10;` translates to `[self setVariable:10];`.  One is a direct write, one calls the setter method.