# Why is window autoreleased AND released in iOS 6 applications?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I haven't done any iOS development since iOS 3, so my memory is a little hazy (though memory management was never anything I struggled with and my mind is quite clear on that).

I'm starting a new project and don't understand why the skeleton code is structured the way it is:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc]
                    initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]
                   autorelease];
    // ... snip ...
}
```

1. Why would the window object be autoreleased? I'm pretty sure it never used to be this way in older iOS versions.
2. Where does `_window` come from? Is this just another way to access `[self window]`?

I'd have written this as:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]
                   initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // ... snip ...
}
```

It was always drummed into me *never* to release an autoreleased object, and in fact doing so usually results in a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you second example you are leaking the window object since, the `alloc` will give the object a retain count of 1, the you assign it `_window` via the property which will also retain the object assigned to it.

It's true you should not release an autorelease object, but in the dealloc you are releasing the iVar for the `window` property. You should always release any property that is declared as either retain or strong. (although not when using ARC).
The `_window` is now automatically generated as the iVar for the property `window`.

There some believes that you should not use `self.` properties in `init` or `dealloc`.
Thus the way I do it is:

```
 [_window release], _window = nil;
```

This wil set the `_window` to nil after releasing it, making sure that if any other thread might want to use this it will be calling on `nil`. Which could prevent a crash but could alo create some weird behavior. This is totally up to you.

---

You should move to ARC, which is a complier option to add release/autolease at compiletime fro you. There is no need to added these your self if you set the property correctly when using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out (mostly). The `@property` declaration has the `strong` attribute. Apparently this is new to ARC (which I'm not actually using) and is otherwise just an alias for `retain`, so `self.window = [ ... ]` retains the object, hence the autorelease.

Still not clear on the `_window` variable, but I assume it is just a shortcut.

Comment: As stated in my answer the `_window` is the ivar for the property `window`. I would really suggest using strong over retain to make you code future proof. And you should really look into ARC it will really save you a lot of time and headaches.

Comment: You've probably already found the answer, but in case you haven't. Any property you declare no longer needs to be synthesized, it's optional. If you don't @synthesize a property an ivar is automatically created with an underscore as the first character.

Comment: Cheers mate. I'm a bit more up to speed on all the shiny new stuff now :)

Answer (score 0):

Check what the `window` property memory descriptor is like. I assume it's `strong`/`retain` in  which case when you set the `window` property, it's value is retained thus needs to be released in `dealloc`.

Following your code path.

1. `[UIWindow alloc]` = retainCount of 1.
2. autoreleasing = retainCount of 0
3. setting the self.window bumps the retainCount which now = 1 and is alive until...
4. in `dealloc` you release it, thus retainCount = 0 and the object is deleted

You probably missed out that in later iOS SDKs, auto synthesized properties automatically create instance variables with underscore prefixes. So you could also do `self.window = nil` in your `dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

> *1. Why would the window object be autoreleased? I'm pretty sure it never used to be this way in older iOS versions.*

If window object is not autoreleased, then it results in leak. Since you are using

```
 self.window  = [[[UIWindow alloc] ....]autorelease];
```

`self.` syntax allows setter function to get called, which retains the object once. So the actual window object which we alloced using `[UIWindow alloc]` should be released, hence `autorelease`. The retain using `self.` syntax is conceptually released in dealloc. So for one alloc plus one retain we are releasing twice.

> Where does _window come from? Is this just another way to access
>   `[self window]`.

Well this question is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work)